# How can you do romantic character development without writing romantic dialogues?

Tags: creative-writing, characters, plot, romance

How can you do romantic character development without writing romantic dialogues? I am bad at writing romantic dialogues, so I was wondering if it was possible to make so that two characters develop genuine and romantic feelings to each other without writing romantic dialogues that are Twilightesque. Is it possible to keep it to a minimum and just imply that romantic relationships are slowly developing without showing what's causing these romantic feeling to develop or is this some kind of plot hole?

Comment: Well, they do say "Actions speak louder than words." You can imply a growing bond with growing trust, caring and protectiveness, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Oh this one is my favorite.

1. they understand each other in vulnerable moments
2. they can control each other. (now I do not mean this in a manipulative way but rather in a "stay put!" kinda way. Does that make sense?)
3. they listen to each. (you don't need to make them have deep exchanges, just when the times comes they actually take each others advice)

4)they PROTECT EACH OTHEr (this one is probably the most cliché but yes it's necessary)

Now this was the first part of your questions. And for the Second part I would say.  Yes.  It's absolutely possible. Have you read the detective novel Tokyo zodiac murders? In there the romantic tension between the detective and his side kick was huge. But never once did they exchange any corny dialogues.
From reading that book I can yield some advices for you.

1. make one of the characters desperate for trying to understand the other to the point that they are obsessively thinking only about the other
2. one the romantic interests would go lengths and break out of there own comfort zone so that their love interest's goals can happen.
3. As the plot advances make one of them observe little things about the other, like suddenly they are observing how their lips curve into a puffy little pout when they are upset,  or how they look really mad when eating good food. Or how they fold their clothes neatly and perfectly taking all the time in the world or how they tuck their hair behind their ears or how delicately they would work towards they goal. I could go on TBH.
4. Make one of the characters show off, like for example.
   mc : "he will always chose me"
   He : *chooses mc*
   Mc: told you.  *sly smile*

mc : he used to cook for me secretly when everyone was sleeping
He : *gets shy*

5. they like to hold hands. Through the forest,  through their adventures they hold hand. Why? *mc comes up with excuses* but they never ask any questions or make any sound when it happens. It's like a little moment between the two of them that slows down their breathing as they feel the softness of each other palm. Mc: *gets embarrassed* "your palms are so sweaty like a old man" *hahah* . Which brings me to my next point which is -
6. teasing. They tease each other a lot and it is mutual and perfect.

That's all I can think of right now